# Formatting html email for Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have an html newsletter which works in most email clients, but the formatting is messed up in Outlook.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color: #98AFC7;
  } 
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1px solid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px" width="600" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height:auto; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 60px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="top" style="padding: 10px; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;" ><center>Email not displaying correctly?<a href="#"><strong> View it in your browser</strong></a></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; height: 80px; text-align: center; padding: 10px;"><img src="http://demo.frostmiller.com/email/img/banner.jpg" alt="Banner will go here" align="middle" style="border: 1px solid;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border: 0; cellspacing: 0; cellpadding: 10px; height: auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="baseline" style="padding: 10px; width:400px; border: 1px solid; halign: top;">
                    <h3>Top Stories</h3> 
                        <ul>
                            <li>Topic 1</li>
                            <li>Topic 2</li>
                            <li>Topic 3</li>
                        </ul>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="baseline" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid;">
                        <h3>Latest News</h3>
                        <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,  
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td cellpadding="10px" style="border: 1px solid; cellspacing: 0;  width: 100%; height: auto; text-align: center;">
            <strong>Copyright &copy 2011 Frost Miller Group </strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid; cellspacing: 0; cellpadding: 10px; width: 100%; height: auto">
            <center>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="#">Trademarks</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="#">Privacy Statement</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="#">Site Feedback</a>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What changes do I need to make in order to get it to display correctly in Outlook?

Comment: **seealso:** https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-code-emails-for-outlook-2016/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To be able to give you *specific* help, you's have to explain what particular parts *specifically* "get messed up", or perhaps offer a screenshot. It also helps to know what version of Outlook you encounter the problem in.

Either way, [CampaignMonitor.com's CSS guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) has often helped me out debugging email client inconsistencies.

From that guide you can see **several things just won't work well or at all in Outlook**, here are some highlights of the more important ones:

- Various types of more sophisticated **selectors**, e.g. `E:first-child`, `E:hover`, `E > F` (Child combinator), `E + F` (Adjacent sibling combinator), `E ~ F` (General sibling combinator). This unfortunately means resorting to workarounds like inline styles.
- Some font properties, e.g. `white-space` won't work.
- The `background-image` property won't work.
- There are several issues with the Box Model properties, most importantly `height`, `width`, and the `max-` versions are either not usable or have bugs for certain elements.
- Positioning and Display issues (e.g. `display`, `float`s and `position` are all out).

In short: **combining CSS and Outlook can be a pain**. Be prepared to use many ugly workarounds.

PS. In your specific case, there are two minor issues in your html that may cause you odd behavior. There's "`align=top`" where you probably meant to use `vertical-align`. Also: `cell-padding` for `td`s doesn't exist.

Comment: Many years later, Microsoft Outlook 2013 still has the same HTML rendering engine as Outlook 2007.  :(

Comment: @Zarepheth Aye, I revisit my own answer too every 6 to 18 months, sometimes I even land here when Googling.

Comment: One useful addition I stumbled upon: to actually test how an HTML email renders in Outlook, you can open the HTML file in Word, both MS Office applications use the same rendering engine.

Comment: Aah ! Its 2022 and still the same issue

Comment: 2024, same issue still.

Answer (score 17):

You should definitely check out the MSDN on what Outlook will support in regards to css and html. The link is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx. If you do not have at least office 2007 you really need to upgrade as there are major differences between 2007 and previous editions. Also try saving the resulting email to file and examine it with firefox you will see what is being changed by outlook and possibly have a more specific question to ask. You can use Word to view the email as a sort of preview as well (but you won't get info on what styles are/are not being applied.

Comment: Saving as an HTML and then examining it in a browser is a great recommendation (and just massively helped me) - thank you

Answer (score 1):

I used VML(Vector Markup Language) based formatting in my email template.
In VML Based you have write your code within comment 

I took help from this site.

https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design#supporttable

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers and actually answer the question in your post.