# why outlook web and outlook client rendering different versions of html email template?

Tags: html, templates, outlook

Here is my code of html template, it is working fine in outlook web but completely going off in outlook client.

```html
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-content" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;">
            <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
              <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                <table bgcolor="#ffffff" class="es-content-body" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:20px;padding-left:45px;padding-right:70px;">
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                        <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                          <td width="560" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                            <table style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                      border-collapse: collapse;
                      width: 100%;
                      color: #32618b;">
                              <tr style="height:25px">
                                <td style="
                                  background: #9bb0e8;
                                  width: 18.1%;
                                  color: white;
                                  font-size: 12px;
                                  font-weight: 600;
                                  border-left: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                                  border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                                  border-top: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                                  border-bottom: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                                  text-align: center;
                                  vertical-align: middle;
                              " rowspan="2">Instructor-led<br>Training
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align:left; border-right: 1px solid #0303ab; font-size:12px; font-weight: 600; background:#acbdeb;font-style:italic;border-top:2px solid #6f93f3;border-right:2px solid #6f93f3;    padding-left: 6px;">Instructor-led</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right; background:#acbdeb; padding-right:6px;border-right:2px solid #6f93f3;border-top:2px solid #6f93f3">
                                    <span style="font-size:11; font-weight: 600"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                    <span style="font-size:10px;">(the avg. per person learning hours is)</span>
                                </td>  
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="height:25px">

                                <td style="text-align:left; font-size:12px; border-right: 1px solid #0303ab; font-weight: 600;font-style:italic;border-right:2px solid #6f93f3;    padding-left: 6px;">Online</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:6px;border-right:2px solid #6f93f3">
                                    <span style="font-size:11; font-weight: 600"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                    <span style="font-size:10px;">(the avg. per person learning hours is)</span></td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr style="height:25px">
                                <td style="
                                  background: #9bb0e8;
                                  width: 18%;
                                  color: white;
                                  font-size: 12px;
                                  font-weight: 600;
                                  border-left: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                                  border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                                  border-bottom: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                                  text-align: center;
                                  vertical-align: middle;
                              " rowspan="2">Online<br>Training </td>
                                <td style="text-align:left; font-size:12px; border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3; border-top:2px solid #6f93f3; font-weight: 600;background:#acbdeb;font-style:italic;padding-left: 6px;">Instructor-led</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right; font-size:10px;background:#acbdeb;padding-right:6px; border-top:2px solid #6f93f3;border-right:2px solid #6f93f3">(Excel file attached)</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="height:25px">

                                <td style="text-align:left;padding-left: 6px; font-size:12px; font-weight: 600; border-bottom:2px solid #6f93f3;font-style:italic;border-right:2px solid #6f93f3">Online</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right; font-size:10px;padding-right:6px;border-right:2px solid #6f93f3;border-bottom:2px solid #6f93f3">(Excel file attached)</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <!-- upskilling programs 5 rows -->
                      <table style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                                                  border-collapse: collapse;
                                                  width: 100%;
                                                  color: #32618b;">
                        <tr style="height:25px; ">
                          <td style="background: #9bb0e8;
                            width: 18%;
                            color: white;
                            font-size: 13px;
                            border-left: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            text-align: center;
                            vertical-align: middle;
                            border-bottom: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            font-weight: 600;" rowspan='5' ;>Upskilling
                            <br>Programs </td>
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:12px; font-weight: 600;background:#acbdeb; width:43%; border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3; font-style:italic;padding-left: 6px;">Program</td>
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:12px; font-weight: 600;background:#acbdeb;padding-left: 6px; border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;  width:40%; font-style:italic; ">Completion Status
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px">
                          <td style="text-align:left;padding-left: 6px; font-size:11px;padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 2px; border-right:2px solid #6f93f3;"></td>
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px; background:#acbdeb;">
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 3px;padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 2px;border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;"></td>
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px; border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;padding-left: 6px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px">
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 2px;border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;padding-left: 6px;"></td>
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px; border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;padding-left: 6px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px; background:#acbdeb;">
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 2px;border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;padding-left: 6px;
                          border-bottom: 2px solid #6F93F3;"></td>
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3; padding-left: 6px;
                          border-bottom: 2px solid #6F93F3; ; border-bottom-color: #6F93F3;"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <!-- Certifications done 4 rows -->
                      <table style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                                            border-collapse: collapse;
                                            width: 100%;
                                            color: #32618b;">
                        <tr style="height:25px">
                          <td style="
                            background: #9bb0e8;
                            width: 18%;
                            color: white;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            font-weight: 600;
                            border-left: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            border-bottom-width: 2px;
                            border-bottom-color: #6F93F3;
                            border-bottom: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            text-align: center;
                            vertical-align: middle;
                        " rowspan="4">Certifications
                            <br>Done</td>
                          <td style="text-align:left;padding-left: 6px; font-size:11px; width:81%; border-style: none solid none none;
                          border-right-width: 1.5pt;border-right-color: #6F93F3;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px; background:#acbdeb;">

                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;border-style: none solid none none;border-right-width: 1.5pt;
                          border-right-color: #6F93F3;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px;">

                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px; border-style: none solid none none;
                          border-right-width: 1.5pt; border-right-color: #6F93F3;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px; background:#acbdeb;">

                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;border-style: none solid none none;
                          border-right-width: 1.5pt;
                          border-right-color: #6F93F3;
border-bottom: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                          "></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <!-- Enrolled but not attended -->
                      <table style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                      border-collapse: collapse;
                      width: 100%;
                      color: #32618b;">
                        <tr style="height:25px">
                          <td style="
                            background: #9bb0e8;
                            width: 18%;
                            color: white;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            font-weight: 600;
                            border-left: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            border-bottom: 2px solid #6f93f3;
                            text-align: center;
                            vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="4">Enrolled
                            <br>But Not
                            <br>Attended</td>
                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;width:81%;border-right: 2px solid #6f93f3;padding-left: 6px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px; background:#acbdeb;">

                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px; border-style: none solid none none;
                          border-right-width: 1.5pt; border-right-color: #6F93F3;"> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px">

                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;border-style: none solid none none;
                          border-right-width: 1.5pt; border-right-color: #6F93F3;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height:25px; background:#acbdeb;border-bottom: 2px solid #6f93f3;">

                          <td style="text-align:left; font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;border-style: none solid none none;
                          border-right-width: 1.5pt; border-right-color: #6F93F3;"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

this table is distorting in table,actually the  right end td borders are not coming in the outlook client software, I am using windows 10, outlook 2016, using UiPath to test it. I used putsmail.com and that worked well though

Please help out expers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting html email for Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861714/formatting-html-email-for-outlook)

Answer (score 1):

Desktop Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016 and 2019 use Word's HTML rendering code, whereas on the web it's rendered by the user's browser in-situ.

Outlook 97-2003 used `mshtml.dll` (aka Trident, Internet Explorer's engine) to render HTML emails. Because Outlook used Word to compose HTML emails but used Internet Explorer to view them, this made email's appearance inconsistent for users of Outlook - Microsoft's decision was to use Word for both composing and viewing - which in my opinion was a colossal mistake that held back HTML email by decades and continues to hold it back as it's now the lowest-common-denominator (this is because Word's support for HTML and CSS features is little beyond what Internet Explorer 5.x supported, so forget about using things like Flexbox and CSS Grids).